Azure WAF exclusion
I would like to ask you for help in creating an Azure WAF rule exclusion.
You can see the blocked URL details here: https://imgur.com/B2cLtbd (blocked by Anomaly score) or below:
requestUri_s
/Account/RegisterConfirmation?userId=CODE&code=CODE&redirectUrl=https://XYXYXYXY.com/EventRegistration/RegisterLink?parentId=CODE

ruleSetVersion_s
3.2
ruleId_s
931130
action_s
Matched
details_message_s
Pattern match ^(?i:file|ftps?|https?)://(.*)$; Begin With RequestHeaders:host at TX:rfi_parameter_.*.

details_data_s
{https://XYXYXYXY.com/EventRegistration/RegisterLink?parentId=CODE found within [ARGS:redirectUrl:https://XYXYXYXY.com/EventRegistration/RegisterLink?parentId=CODE]} and { found within [TX:rfi_parameter_args:redirecturl:XYXYXYXY.com/EventRegistration/RegisterLink?parentId=CODE]}

details_file_s
REQUEST-931-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RFI.conf
.
.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged.

Try creating a custom WAF policy by defining the rule to execute 'redirectUrl' parameter being checked for that pattern.
Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview to create a policy

Yes, I found the same Vinay B. :) thank you

SOLVED
This got solved by adding exclusion to the mentioned rule:
Req Arg Nam > Contains > redirectUrl
Refering to the last Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-waf-configuration?tabs=portal#next-steps
